# VLC Server Communication with .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, video-streaming, vlc

I am working on a project that allows for video streaming or video-on-demand. I've looked for software packages and VLC looks like an excellent choice for low cost needs.

In order to really work with this application I need an API that can communicate with the system. After doing some research there were some bindings via PHP and Java but nothing that is truely .NET. I looked further and found that I can communicate via telnet which is viable for the work I need.

I started working on the project but first did manual workflow tests since the API I'd create would be an automation later. I was able to launch VLC but had much difficult making it play streaming media as well as get the telnet session active. This was after reading the examples in the documentation which appear to not work any more or work differently so I'm considering that resource unreliable.

Is there any examples using the current 0.9.8 release of VLC that actually has working communication examples out there? Also, are there any bindings that I could possibly use to communicate with .NET to VLC that might have been just out of my reach to find on the internet?

Comment: I'm wondering why you didn't chose to use a flash video player rather than VLC instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look like [vlcremote](http://vlcremote.sourceforge.net/) would be a good starting point, its written in C#.