# Launching applications silently?

Tags: c++, vlc

My C++ application calls VLC as a subprocess. Is there a way to avoid having the GUI pop-up? I am looking for a Mac and a Windows solution. Hackish workarounds are welcome too.

PS: I know there is such a thing as cvlc (command-line version of VLC), but I haven't found any builds for it online. You do get it when you make the build yourself, but that hasn't worked out yet on my Snow Leopard machine. I also need a Windows version, but I don't feel courageous enough to attempt making a VLC build myself on this platform.

**Solved**

All I had to do was add the "-I dummy" parameters.

Comment: What does " Is there a way to avoid having the GUI pop-up?" mean?
You can make something start minimised.

Comment: @Dave Hillier it means that nothing visibly happens on the computer screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. VLC allows you to start without GUI by using:

`VLC -I dummy`
Starts the "dummy" interface.
`VLC -I rc`
Starts the "remote control" interface, which allows you to send commands using the stdin channel.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785829/vlc-remotely-control-from-c/785862#785862)

Answer (score 0):

When you create the VLC instance using the libvlc_new function you have a VLC arguments to not display VLC interface. See this [small example](http://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial).